# docker python sdk with buildarg and copy not doing as intended

Tags: python, docker

I have below folder structure:

```
    main
        |
        |-->build
           |
           |-->pipelines/files.txt
        |
        |-->dockerfile
        |-->dockerBuild.py
```

my dockerBuild.py looks like this:

```
 docker_location = '/main'
            pipeline_file_path = docker_location + '/build/pipelines' 
      # pipeline_file_path = '/build/pipelines' tried with this one as well
            self.docker_client.images.build(path=docker_location,
                                                nocache='no_cache',
                                                rm=True,
                                                tag=self.local_repository_tag,
                                                buildargs={'PIPELINE': pipeline_file_path})
```

now Dockerfile looks like this

```
ARG PIPELINE
... 
COPY --chown=user:user ${PIPELINE}/pipelines/  "${S_HOME}"/pipeline2load/
```

So, when I run my `dockerBuild.py` it complains can't find pipelines to copy the file? 
I have tried both absolute path and the path from where dockerbuild is running, but in both cases it can't find the files? so any pointer how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke the builder, the *context* is your `main` directory (what you're passing as the `path` argument).  Within the Dockerfile, the first argument to the `COPY` command is always a *relative* path (even if it starts with `/`) interpreted relative to that context directory.

That means you don't need the `ARG` specifying where the content is; you know how the host filesystem is laid out and you can just `COPY` from where it's starting.  (I also wouldn't use an environment variable or argument for file paths inside the container, since you'll usually want to build with something fixed.)

```sh
COPY ./build/pipelines/ /s_home/pipeline2load/
```

In your specific example, you're passing the equivalent of `--build-arg PIPELINE=/main/build/pipelines`, and then that gets expanded in the `COPY` directive; so you're trying to copy in `./main/build/pipelines/pipelines` relative to the `/main` directory.  As you have it, it would build if you set

```python
buildargs={'PIPELINE': 'build'}
```

but I feel like spelling out concrete paths in the Dockerfile is clearer.

Comment: I was under same impression that `COPY ./build/pipelines/ /s_home/pipeline2load/` will work, but python-sdk complains then I have to add the build argument to pass the path.

Comment: If your Dockerfile still has `ARG PIPELINE` with no default value then passing some value for it is required.  But if you're not using the argument you can delete that line.